# Polyglossia and navigator interference

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I noticed that loading the `navigator`package breaks my xeLaTeX documents if I use `polyglossia` as well.

```
%!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{navigator}

\begin{document}

Hello!

\end{document}
```

XeLaTeX stops with

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \baselineskip 
l.706
```

Is there a way around?

Comment: Load `navigator` before setting the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `navigator` doesn't take precautions against category code changes and uses in a couple of places `"`, which the German module of `polyglossia` makes active.

This of course confuses the macros and the result is the error you see.

Load `navigator` before setting languages and all should be OK.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{navigator}

\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\begin{document}

Hello!

\end{document}
```

Comment: egrep's answer is perfect when it is about German. Unfortunately, it breaks again when using russian as main or default language. I will investigate it and will share details if any.